# Print only the 1st last name

Tags: biblatex

I am using mik-tex latex.

I need to reference my sources with capital last names, this definition kinda works

```
\DeclareNameFormat{}{\uppercase{#1}}
```

but it does only work if there is only one author.
When there are many authors, the last names follow each other, which is not what i want.

It should only print the last name of the first author.

*Minimal example:*

latex file

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
ngerman
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{minimal.bib}

% sources should be the last name and in capital letters
\DeclareNameFormat{}{\uppercase{#1}}


\begin{document}

this works \cite{lakos1996large}. This doesn't work \cite{rajkovicusing}.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

minimal.bib

```
@article{lakos1996large,
title={Large-scale C++ software design},
author={Lakos, John},
journal={Reading, MA},
year={1996}
}

@article{rajkovicusing,
title={Using CQRS Pattern for Improving Performances in Medical Information Systems},
author={Rajkovi{\'c}, Petar and Jankovi{\'c}, Dragan and Milenkovi{\'c}, Aleksandar},
year = {2013}
}
```

Comment: Which TeX dialect are you using? It seems that there should be `\MakeUppercase`...

Answer (score 3):

Name formats as declared via `\DeclareNameFormat` are primarily to format the order of name parts (i.e. first last, last first, etc. pp.).

To change the way names are displayed, `biblatex` provides wrapper macros.
So you want to you use

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
```

to format last names and

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
```

to format first names.
(I have used the LaTeX command `\MakeUppercase` instead of the TeX `\uppercase` command. For more on that see [Case-changing oddities](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange) on the UK List of TeX Frequently Asked Questions on the Web)

You might also want to have a look at

```
\mkbibnamelast{}
\mkbibnamefirst{}
\mkbibnameprefix{}
\mkbibnameaffix{}
```

To format last names, first names, name prefixes (such as "von", "van", "de la" etc.) and affixes (such as "Jr.", "Sr.", "III" etc.) respectively.

See § 4.10.1 *User-definable Commands and Hooks* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Consider this usage example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Uthor,
  author = {von Uthor, Jr., Arnold},
  year = {2001},
  title = {The Work},
}
@misc{UthorA,
  author = {Uthor, Arnold},
  year = {2011},
  title = {The Work II},
  subtitle = {Return of the Work},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Be advised though that all uppercase is typographically and stylistically questionable, your document might benefit from using small caps. Maybe try

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

instead.